# Return rows in a resultset when no record found for particular date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a query to return following output.

```
Date          Day      Sale Qty     Purchase Qty      Transfer Qty
------------------------------------------------------------------
05/04/2015    1           11             0                0
07/04/2015    3            0            16                0
08/04/2015    4           12            14               17
11/04/2015    7            1             2                0
```

My current query is as follows.

```
(select T1.Date,T1.Day,T1.SaleQty,0 as PurchaseQty,0 as TransferQty from SaleTable T1)
union all
(select T2.Date,T2.Day,0 as SaleQty,T2.PurchaseQty,0 as TransferQty from PurchaseTable T2)
union all
(select T3.Date,T3.Day,0 as SaleQty,0 as PurchaseQty,T3.TransferQty from TransferTable T3)
```

Required output is in the following format

```
Date          Day      Sale Qty     Purchase Qty      Transfer Qty
------------------------------------------------------------------
05/04/2015    1           11             0                0
06/04/2015    2            0             0                0
07/04/2015    3            0            16                0
08/04/2015    4           12            14               17
09/04/2015    5            0             0                0
10/04/2015    6            0             0                0
11/04/2015    7            1             2                0
```

How should I write query to return rows with date and day when no result set is returned for that date output.

Comment: You are going to need to perform an outer join against a list of dates.

Comment: You may want to introduce a so called "numbers" table. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

Answer (score 1):

You need a table to act as a lookup table for the dates and days that are missing to cover the range of dates in the query results. You can create one like so:

```
-- add a temp table for your sample data
CREATE TABLE #Results
    ([Date] datetime, [Day] int, [Sale Qty] int, [Purchase Qty] int, [Transfer Qty] int)
;
-- insert your sample data
INSERT INTO #Results
    ([Date], [Day], [Sale Qty], [Purchase Qty], [Transfer Qty])
VALUES
    ('2015-04-05 00:00:00', 1, 11, 0, 0),
    ('2015-04-07 00:00:00', 3, 0, 16, 0),
    ('2015-04-08 00:00:00', 4, 12, 14, 17),
    ('2015-04-11 00:00:00', 7, 1, 2, 0)
;
-- find the max date
DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME = (SELECT TOP 1 [Date] FROM #Results ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
-- recursive cte to build the date & day lookup table
;WITH cte AS (
    -- cte anchor is the min date and day = 1
    SELECT MIN([Date]) AS DateValue, 1 AS [Day] 
    FROM #Results
    UNION ALL
    -- uses dateadd to increment days until @MaxDate reached
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte.DateValue), [Day] +1
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte.DateValue) <= @MaxDate
)
-- inserts values into temp lookup table
SELECT * 
INTO #DateLookup
FROM cte
```

This will create a temp table with the range of values using the lowest and highest dates in your results that holds these values:

```
DateValue                Day
----------------------------
2015-04-05 00:00:00.000  1
2015-04-06 00:00:00.000  2
2015-04-07 00:00:00.000  3
2015-04-08 00:00:00.000  4
2015-04-09 00:00:00.000  5
2015-04-10 00:00:00.000  6
2015-04-11 00:00:00.000  7
```

You will then need to link to this table and replace any `NULL` values with `0` like so:

```
SELECT #DateLookup.[DateValue] AS [Date],
       #DateLookup.[Day] ,
       COALESCE([Sale Qty],0) AS [Sale Qty],
       COALESCE([Purchase Qty],0) AS [Purchase Qty],
       COALESCE([Transfer Qty],0) AS [Transfer Qty]
FROM #DateLookup
LEFT JOIN #Results ON #DateLookup.DateValue = #Results.[Date]

-- some tidy up
DROP TABLE #Results
DROP TABLE #DateLookup
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a dates table in your system, add one. you can use this t-sql script:

```
CREATE TABLE TblDates(TheDate date not null);

DECLARE @StartDate date,
        @NumberOfDates int,
        @Counter int

SELECT @StartDate = GETDATE(), -- or whatever date you want
       @NumberOfDates = 100, -- or whatever number of dates you want after start date
       @Counter = 0;

WHILE(@Counter < @NumberOfDates)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TblDates(TheDate) VALUES (DATEADD(d, @Counter, @StartDate)
END
```

After running this script you should have a dates table ready to use.
Then all you have to do is this:

```
SELECT TheDate, 
       DATEPART(D, TheDate) As Day, 
       ISNULL(T1.SaleQty, 0) As SaleQty, 
       ISNULL(T2.PurchaseQty, 0) As PurchaseQty,
       ISNULL(T3.TransferQty, 0) As TransferQty
FROM tblDates LEFT JOIN 
SaleTable T1 ON(TheDate = T1.Date) LEFT JOIN
PurchaseTable T2 ON(TheDate = T2.Date) LEFT JOIN
TransferTable T3 ON(TheDate = T3.Date)
```

### Update

Now that i think about it, you can use a numbers table to create a cte that will hold your dates (creating the numbers table is fairly simple and much like the script I wrote for the dates table)

```
With DatesCTE(TheDate) AS
  SELECT DATEADD(D, TheNumber, @startDate)
  FROM NumbersTable
  WHERE DATEADD(D, TheNumber, @StartDate) < @EndDate
```

### Update 2

As [Selva TS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311255/selva-ts) mentioned in a comment to this answer, it's possible to generate a dates cte even without a numbers table, using recursive cte like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime
SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()),  @EndDate = GETDATE()

;WITH Calendar AS(
    SELECT @StartDate dateidx
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateidx + 1
    FROM   Calendar
    WHERE dateidx + 1 < @EndDate
)
```

Comment: We can generate the calendar by using `Tally Table`. Please refer this https://rdineshkumar.wordpress.com/tag/calendar-generation-sql-server-2008/