# Showing Data for those Dates which are not present in Database Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying show attendance record for `employees` in particular Branch, let Say "Pune Branch".

While Showing Weekly Records, It only shows the record of dates for which there is an entry in database table. I also want to show record for those Date on which there is no any employee present.

Suppose In `Log_TB` there are 2 employee record present for `28 Apr 2015` out of 2 Employees, Then It Shows

[image: Then It Shows]

And If No records for that Date then it Returns nothing.

I want result Like

[image: I want result Like]

Here is my Query

```
Declare
@Date date = GETDATE(),
@date1 date,
@Total int

    set @date1 = (CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DD,-6,@Date),108));

    select @Total = Count(User_TB.User_Id) 
    from User_TB join Branch_TB 
    on User_TB.User_Branch = Branch_TB.Branch_Name 
    where User_TB.User_Branch = 'Pune';

    select convert(varchar,Log_TB.Date,106) AS Date,
    CONVERT(CHAR(3),DATENAME(weekday,Log_TB.Date)) AS Day,
    @Total AS Total,COUNT(Log_TB.User_Id) Present,
    (@Total-COUNT(Log_TB.User_Id)) AS Absent 
    From Log_TB join User_TB on Log_TB.User_Id = User_TB.User_Id 
    where Log_TB.Date <= (CONVERT(date,@Date,108)) 
    and Log_TB.Date >= @date1 and User_TB.User_Branch = 'Pune'
    group by Log_TB.Date;
```

My table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log_TB]
(
[User_Id] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[First_Login] [time](0) NULL,
[Logout] [time](0) NULL,
[Date] [date] NULL,
[Working_Hrs] [time](0) NULL,
[extra_Int] [int] NOT NULL,
[extra_String] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return rows in a resulset when no record found for particular date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647405/return-rows-in-a-resulset-when-no-record-found-for-particular-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a `Numbers` or a `Date` table. You can generate it using something like this

```
DECLARE @date1 DATE = '20150401',@Date DATE= GETDATE();
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT @date1 as datecol
UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(day,1,datecol) FROM CTE WHERE DATEADD(day,1,datecol) <= @Date
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

In your query, you would use it like this

```
Declare
@Date date = GETDATE(),
@date1 date,
@Total int

set @date1 = (CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DD,-6,@Date),108));

select @Total = Count(User_TB.User_Id) 
from User_TB join Branch_TB 
on User_TB.User_Branch = Branch_TB.Branch_Name 
where User_TB.User_Branch = 'Pune';

DECLARE @date1 DATE = '20150401',@Date DATE= GETDATE();
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT @date1 as datecol
UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(day,1,datecol) FROM CTE WHERE     DATEADD(day,1,datecol) <= @Date
)
select convert(varchar,CTE.datecol,106) AS Date,
CONVERT(CHAR(3),DATENAME(weekday,CTE.datecol)) AS Day,
@Total AS Total,COUNT(User_TB.User_Id) Present,
(@Total-COUNT(User_TB.User_Id)) AS Absent 
From CTE LEFT JOIN Log_TB ON Log_TB.Log_TB.Date = CTE.datecol
LEFT join User_TB on Log_TB.User_Id = User_TB.User_Id 
and User_TB.User_Branch = 'Pune'
group by CTE.datecol;
```

Comment: This helps me @ughai. But Log_TB has records for two branches as gives proper output for that Date on which there no records for any branch. But if there is record for one Branch and not for  another branch.. Still it shows the present record for that another branch .. can you please help me little more

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @date datetime   -- its a starting date 
Set @Date = '1-Apr-2015'


Declare @table table (date datetime)
-- inserts data from starting date till getdate
while @date <> convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101),101)
begin
    insert into @table
    select @date aa
    select @date = @date+1
end

select * from @table
```

Just join @table and your data with left join

```
Select * 
from @table left join (Your data) with condition date.
```

Comment: You can try editing your answer and apply some formatting so that it is clear to everyone what are the important points